# Does the monks extra flurry attack ki attack stack with haste/speed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, attack

If a monk has a hasted/speed monk weapon and performs a flurry of blows, are they able to spend a ki point to gain another attack in addition to the one granted by haste/speed?

[Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste)

> When making a full attack action, a hasted creature may make one extra attack with one natural or manufactured weapon. The attack is made using the creature’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This effect is not cumulative with similar effects, such as that provided by a speed weapon, nor does it actually grant an extra action, so you can’t use it to cast a second spell or otherwise take an extra action in the round.)

[Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed/)

> When making a full-attack action, the wielder of a speed weapon may make one extra attack with it. The attack uses the wielder’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a haste spell.)

[Ki Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Ki-Pool-Su-)

> Make one additional attack at his highest attack bonus when making a flurry of blows attack

Is the ki attack considered similar enough due to both the restriction of only working with flurry attack and expending a ki point to the effect of speed/haste?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, you gain an additional attack

From the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qk0):

> *Does the extra attack from spending ki as part of a flurry of blows stack with the extra attack from haste?*
>
> Yes. The extra attack described in the ki pool ability doesn't say it works like haste, nor does it say that it doesn't stack with haste, so the monk would get two additional attacks (one from spending a ki point as part of a flurry, one from haste).